# SVG HTML - Is it possible to line up x Circles onto of an existing Path?

Tags: html, svg, path, geometry, positioning

I've Created a Method which creates me custom Paths looking like Stars and now I want to line up x amount of Circles onto this Path. How is this possible and is there a way to automate this?

Here are some [Possible Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqgmI.png). I want the black Path line to Look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0BHR.png). But it is necessary for me that I can exactly define the Amount of Circles on the Path.

Thanks for your Help :D

Comment: Maybe apply SVG markers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the length of your path with `.getTotalLength()`, and then distribute as many circles along the path as you want, determining the points with `.getPointAtLength(position)`.

```js
const r = 2;

const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

const line = document.querySelector('.line');
const circles = document.querySelector('.circles');

const length = line.getTotalLength();

function drawCircles(number) {
  circles.textContent = '';
  
  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    const point = line.getPointAtLength(i * length / number);
    
    const circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    circle.setAttribute('r', r);
    circle.setAttribute('cx', point.x);
    circle.setAttribute('cy', point.y);
    
    circles.appendChild(circle);
  }
}

drawCircles(40);
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
}
.circles {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.2px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path class="line" d="M 50,10 40,40 10,50 40,60 50,90 60,60 90,50 60,40 Z" />
  <g class="circles" />
</svg>
```

From your example picture, I get that you want to style the circles with both a fill and a stroke. This makes it necessary to really compute positions of the circles. If the circles only had a monochrome fill and no stroke, there would be an easier solution.

Set the `pathLength` attribute to the number of circles you want to draw and define `stroke-dasharray="0 1"`. This draws a dash of length 0 with distance 1 between the dashes. If you combine that with `stroke-linecap: round`, each of the zero-length dashes is drawn as a circle.

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 4;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path class="line" pathLength="40" d="M 50,10 40,40 10,50 40,60 50,90 60,60 90,50 60,40 Z" />
</svg>
```